# react build with gh-pages generates wrong file path to static files

Tags: reactjs, build, github-pages

Hello fellow programmers!

I'm trying to deploy an application with help of the npm library gh-pages. The issue i'm encountering is that the index.html in my build folder is wrongly adding my repository name to the static file path.

According to the documentation my homepage field in my package.json should look like this

```
"homepage": "https://username.github.io/repoName/",
```

However when i enter the website url i get 404 error code because it's looking for my static files in

```
"/repoName/static/js/main.34abd32a.chunk.js"
```

Which is confusing to me since i need to keep my homepage field as it is in order to be able to push it to the gh-pages branch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using CRA? If so, I think the homepage field is causing this issue. When you run `npm run build` it will use the homepage field to set the base url, hence you're looking for files in "/repoName/static/" rather than just "/static/". The gh-pages package places the files at the root of the gh-pages branch however. So "/repoName/static" will give a 404. Just remove the homepage field and I think you should be fine, since the base url will now be "/".

Comment: It seems to be working without the homepage field. You're right, it's that field that caused the issues. Thanks for the help, for some reason i thought it was necessary, looked through multiple videos where they declared it as such.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, static files are served as `repo-name/static/..` which is invalid. Correct one is `/static/..`

I had created app using `npx create-react-app` and using gh-pages (https) with custom domain from google domains

I solved it with below steps

1. In package.json `"homepage": "https:/username.github.io"` (Do not use repo name here)
2. Use `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter` index.js. Below is the code snippet I have

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <App />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  <React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```